# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier at eval anonymous

Tags: model-view-controller, kendo-ui, grid, telerik

I create a test project in MVC with kendo grid with popup edit. In

this scenario I have 3 relational tables. but when I add the third

table, I getting this Error:

```
> VM1362:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
>     at eval (<anonymous>)
at (https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.3.1018/js/jquery.min.js:2:2651)
at `Function.globalEval` (https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.3.1018/js/jquery.min.js:2:2662)
at Ha (https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.3.1018/js/jquery.min.js:3:21262)
at `n.fn.init.append` (https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.3.1018/js/jquery.min.js:3:22791)
at `I.fn.init.n.fn.(anonymous function) [as appendTo]` (https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.3.1018/js/jquery.min.js:3:24510)
at `init._createPopupEditor` (https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.3.1018/js/kendo.all.min.js:52:4953)
at `init.editRow` (https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.3.1018/js/kendo.all.min.js:52:2129)
at `HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous>`
```

if I comment bellow line, project run correctly:

```
@{Html.RenderAction("AgreementExpertsIndex", new { xAgreementID = Model.xID });}
```

Can anyone say what is the problem?
The source code is here:
[source file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/oiw7tc0mfexxhvd/MVCTest1.rar?dl=0)
thanks

Comment: if I remove first grid so I had 2 grid, then project run correctly. Can not be nailed to three stages in kendo grid?

Answer (score 0):

Try a lowercase `M` in `Model`:

```
@{Html.RenderAction("AgreementExpertsIndex", new { xAgreementID = model.xID });}
```